# Is there difference between buckets in mongo time series collection and bucket stage in aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework, bucket

I am confused. My aim is to get data from my collection based on time ranges like data in a day, week and month.

I found almost no implementation for creating a time series collection where I can bucket data liek described in this post.

## Time Series Collection

{
 "timeField": created_at,
"metaField": interaction_type,
"expireAfterSeconds": 2592000
}
**interaction_type:** comment OR like OR view

So I want to retrieve count of each interaction type in last 24 hours, last 7 days, last 30 days.

I have it figured out theoretically, if any of you can help please let me know.

I tried creating the time series collection and inserted around a million documents.

I cannot figure out how to proceed at all.

Comment: let us know what you have tried and the issue that you are facing